# Run an MSI on a remote machine in TFS 2015

Tags: continuous-integration, tfs-2015, continuous-deployment

I have a TFS 2015 build that copies a MSI generated during said build to a remote machine (i.e. not the build agent/build server).

How can I get that MSI to be ran on the remote machine by TFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the build account has access to the remote machine you could potentially execute the msi remotely via psexec.

```
PsExec.exe \\RemoteComputer -d -s cmd /c "msiexec.exe /I "drive:\path\to\yourmsi.msi" /quiet /norestart"
```

Full example can be found here: https://www.itdroplets.com/run-msi-psexec/